# Dependency Library Conflict Results in warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+' to my project

So first there another library that created an conflict with duplicate attr/type, so I removed it and use an alternative. (done)

Then it got error `AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.`

Problem with `module: 'ui_legacy'`

ui_legacy-8.13.0\res\layout\list_preference_layout.xml

```xml
<ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

I created a blank project and implemented all dependencies from original project.

The difference between them is that the blank just warn and BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

But original project results with BUILD FAILED.

You can ask me for more details if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue with an older library I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set ID to android internal ID.
You should set the ID of imageview to `android:id="@+id/icon"`